# Table empties when state updated, need to refresh it

Tags: reactjs

When I change a value in the table, it disappears when I update the state with the new value.  I have checked state and it is updated correctly but the table is now blank. I am using a bootstrap table.

Everything in state is now updated but the grid is empty, can I use useEffect to do rebind the table?

```js
const GridEdit = () => {
  const store = useContext(StoreContext);
  const handleBlur = (e, arrayRow, editableFields) => {
    const newVals = store.gridItems[0][0];

    newVals["Status"] = e.target.innerHTML;
    store.gridItems[1](newVals);
    console.log("hello ", store.gridItems[0]);
  };

  const dataTable = store.gridItems[0];

  function tableHeaders(data) {
    let tableHeaders = [];
    if (data.length > 0) {
      let headers = Object.keys(data[0]);
      headers.map((header) =>
        tableHeaders.push(<th key={header}>{header}</th>)
      );
    }
    if (tableHeaders.length === 0) {
      return null;
    } else return tableHeaders;
  }

  function tableRows(dataTable) {
    let tableLength = dataTable.length;
    let table = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < tableLength; i++) {
      let children = [];
      let row = Object.values(dataTable[i]);
      const readOnlyFields = row.slice(0, 4);
      const editableFields = row.slice(4, 7);
      readOnlyFields.map((data) => children.push(<td id={row[0]}>{data}</td>));
      editableFields.map((data) =>
        children.push(
          <td ContentEditable="true" id={row[0]}>
            {data}
          </td>
        )
      );
      table.push(
        <tr key={row} onBlur={(e) => handleBlur(e, i, editableFields)}>
          {children}
        </tr>
      );
    }
    if (table.length === 0) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return table;
    }
  }

  return (
    <tbody className="tableHeaders">
      <tr>{tableHeaders(dataTable)}</tr>
      {tableRows(dataTable)}
    </tbody>
  );
};

export default GridEdit;
```

Comment: How can we help you without seeing the code?

Comment: sorry, I was formatting it

Comment: suggestion: [react-table](https://react-table.tanstack.com/) might be help you.